# Ability: conditions dependent on the object (allow :create only for team_members)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authorization, ruby-on-rails-5, cancan, cancancan

## Setup

A basic hotel setup where `users` are team members of a `hotel`. It uses [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) and [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) with Rails 5.2

```
rails g scaffold User name
rails g scaffold Hotel name
rails g scaffold TeamMembership user:references hotel:references
rails g scaffold Reservation starts_on:date ends_on:date hotel:references
rails g scaffold CheckIn hotel:references reservation:references
```

`hotels` are connected to `users` via `has_many :users, through: :team_memberships`. And vice versa for `users` to `hotels`.

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :hotels do
  resources :reservations
  resources :check_ins
end
```

**app/controllers/check_ins_controller.rb**

```
class CheckInsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  load_and_authorize_resource :hotel
  load_and_authorize_resource :check_in, :through => :hotel
[...]
```

**app/models/ability.rb**

```
[...]
can [:read, :destroy], CheckIn, hotel_id: user.hotel_ids
can [:create], CheckIn
[...]
```

## Problem/Question

Somewhere in a view I have this code:

```
<% if can? :create, CheckIn %>
  <%= link_to 'Create Check-In', new_hotel_check_in_path(@hotel) %>
<% end %>
```

It should only be visible to team members of the `@hotel`.

The first line of the `ability.rb` works fine but the second line doesn't work because with that anybody can create a new `check_in` but only `team_memberships` should be able to create a new `check_in` for their hotel.

What is the best way to solve this? Obviously the link shouldn't be displayed but also the `/hotels/:hotel_id/check_ins/new` URL should **not** be accessible for anybody who is not a team member.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem and this is where the `business` logic intersects the `authorization` logic.

There are many opinions on this matter.

1) Many people believe that this kind of intersection is unacceptable. They would advise you to do what you need this way (separating business and authorization logic)

```
<% if can?(:create, CheckIn) && current_user.member_of?(@hotel) %>
  <%= link_to 'Create Check-In', new_hotel_check_in_path(@hotel) %>
<% end %>
```

2) If you are sure you need this you can do it like this:

Add a new permission to `Hotel` model:

```
can [:check_in], Hotel do |hotel|
  user.member_of?(hotel)
end
```

Then in the view:

```
<% if can?(:create, CheckIn) && can?(:check_in, @hotel) %>
  <%= link_to 'Create Check-In', new_hotel_check_in_path(@hotel) %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller:

```
class CheckInsController < ApplicationController
  # ...
  def new
    authorize! :check_in, @hotel
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I understand the solution for the can?() link in the view but how can I secure the access to the plain URL? Even if a non team member doesn't see the link he/she could guess the URL because it's RESTful.

Comment: I don't want non team members to create a `CheckIn`.

Comment: Edited the answer.  Added more info about the controller

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
can [:create], CheckIn if user.team_memberships.present?
```

OR

```
can [:create], CheckIn if user.hotels.present?
```

Hope this helped.